# import multiple *.gql files in a root to a TS file

Tags: typescript, import

I this below hierarchy, I have multiple `*.gql` files that I want to use in a `*.ts` files an then use each of them base on need.

```
fetch.ts
graphql/
├── queries/
│   ├── Me.gql
│   ├── Terminals.gql
│   ├── Sessions.gql
```

How can I import all of them once and if their name was in an anothor array? Can I write something like this and then recieve them as a array or object?

```js
// fetch.js

import * as queries from './graphql/queries'
```